# help with snmp clients?

Tags: router, snmp

i need to get the route table from a router and i think snmp is capable of doing that, any idea of a good snmp client to accomplish this, or, any idea not involving snmp to solve this problem?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your router speaks SNMP *and* is exporting its route table via SNMP then yes, an SNMP client can retrieve this information.

A "good" SNMP client depends on what you're looking for.  As a Unix guy I'd suggest `snmpwalk` from the net-snmp distribution of tools.  Other popular ones include commercial tools like HP OpenView, or the free [MIB Browser from iReasoning](http://ireasoning.com/mibbrowser.shtml).

In any case the MIB you want for the routing table is `1.3.6.1.2.1.4.21` -- this will be a SNMP table that reflects the contents of your IP routing table.  (Thanks to our sister site [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405363/) for popping up in a google search and saving me from having to look through MIB files :-)

Comment: thanks, i'll give it a try to snmpwalk, i asked this question couse at university i'm in a project to find out a level 3 network topology and i think that is not a trivial problem, then i read SNMP specification and if it's possible to get a router table route my problem is almost solved, if you have any idea on this new issue please i will appreciate, thanks very much

Comment: your bigger challenge at university will be getting the SNMP community string (assuming it's not `public`)

Comment: don't think so couse the network admin is working with me, in any case i dont know what the community string is

Answer (score 0):

Use [Net-SNMP](http://www.net-snmp.org/)(OID ip.ipRouteTable.ipRouteEntry) or library for your preferred language. Also, you may use telnet/ssh to remote call command.